# "My room looks like as follow" or "My room looks like the following"

Tags: word-usage, sentence-construction, expressions

I asked a question in another [post](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/32948/24363), where I uploaded an image to demonstrate what my room and said

> My room looks like as follow with concrete walls

and I am considering if both expression are idiomatic?

My room looks like as follow

My room looks like the following

Comment: As follow**s**, but yes both are acceptable.   In your example sentence, I would probably say "as follows, **but** with concrete walls".

Answer (score 1):

"As follows" is really a way to introduce more *text*, often a *list*, for example:

> - My shopping list is as follows: three bananas, one bag of potatoes, three cans of soup.
> - The lyrics to the song are as follows:
>     "We all live in a yellow submarine
>     a yellow submarine...."

You can use "the following" in a similar way:

> - I would like you to buy the following: three bananas...

However, you can refer to other things with "the following", for example, "*in the following photograph*" or "*in the following film clip*".

In the context of your example, you said it was introducing an image. You should, therefore, use "the following", and point to the image, for example:

> My room looks like the following image, with concrete walls.

Comment: This answers the question regarding follows/following very well. But notice there is another issue with the sentence.  It is more idiomatic (or even more semantically correct) to say, “My room looks like **the room in** the following image.” The *image* might be described as being small, vivid, distorted, out of focus, etc but the *room in it* can be described as ”looking like my room”. I am not saying the original sentence’s form of words is not possible and might in fact be frequently used, it’s just that I see it as not entirely idiomatic or ’correct’.